# Constructing a continuous matrix valued function

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, banach-spaces

Given $d<k$. Let ${\cal M}_{d\times k}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of all $d\times k$ real matrices and suppose that $H:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow {\cal M}_{d\times k}(\mathbb{R})$ is a continuous matrices-valued function such that $H(x)$ is full rank for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$.

I'd like to construct a continuous function $K:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow  {\cal M}_{k\times (k-d)}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $K(x)$ is full rank and
\begin{equation}
H(x)K(x)=0, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^k.
\end{equation}
Can we do that?

I've tried defining $K$ as follows: for every $x_0$ define $K(x_0)$ by such matrix with columns are all element in the basis of the subspace $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^k :H(x_0)y=0\}$. Of course $K(x_0)\in {\cal M}_{k\times (k-d)}(\mathbb{R})$ since $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^k :H(x_0)y=0\}$ has dimension $k-d$. But the problem was on the continuity because we can choose arbritary basis of the above subspace. Can anyone give advice in constructing $K$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JIamprong  The Grahm Schmidt process is  a continuous process.    The following link  may help you indirectly   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288912/the-gram-schmidt-process-is-a-deformation-retraction

Comment: Before using Gram–Schmidt, I would notice that the pointwise kernel of the map $H$ defines a vector bundle over the source of $H$. Since the source of $H$ is (paracompact Hausdorff and) contractible, then that vector bundle is trivializable. Now apply the Gram–Schmidt orthogonalization process.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade: I don't know about the source of $H$. Could you explain me more detail. I am not really familiar with this. Thanks

Comment: The source of $H$ means its domain, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^k$ in your case.

Comment: SO, what does "the vector bundle is trivializable" means? Btw, can we construct such matrix?

Comment: In my previous comment, the Gram–Schmidt orthogonalization process is in fact utterly irrelevant. The trivializability of the vector bundle is sufficient to produce the desired map. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: From what I've understood of p.36 of Byrd and Schnabel (1986), [Continuity of the null space basis and constrained optimization](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01589439), Mathematical Programming, 35(1): 32-41, it is not always possible to construct a continuous $K(x)$ on all the $\mathbb{R}^k$. 
However, it is always possible to construct a continuous $K(x)$ in a neighborhood of a point, as outlined in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1203782).

Comment: @RicardoAndrade I found your solution using the trivializability of the vector bundle very interesting! In this case the continuous map $K(x)$ would be given by the fiber of the vector bundle, right? However, from what I've understood of [Byrd and Schnabel's paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01589439), it is not always possible to construct a continuous map $K(x)$. Could  it be the case that the pointwise 
kernel of the map $H$ does not always define a vector bundle over $\mathbb{R}^k$, or I'm missing something? 
Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer that requires an additional hypothesis:

- $\forall x$, every *principal submatrix* of $H(x)$ has to be non singular.

Here, we define the principal submatrices of a generic matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{d \times k}$ as the matrices $A^{(1)},\ldots,A^{(d)}$ given by $A^{(m)}\in\mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ and $[A^{(m)}]_{i,j} = [A]_{i,j}$ for each $m = 1,\ldots,d$.

Now for each $x$ you compute the row echelon form of $H(x)$  by means of *gaussian elimination*, resulting into the matrix $E(x)$. This process is continuous because you don't need pivoting, thanks to the initial hypothesis. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)

Now, you have
$$E(x)= \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & * &      * & * & * & \cdots & * \\
  & 1 &      * & * & * & \cdots & * \\
  &   & \ddots & \ddots  &   &        & \vdots\\
  &   &        & 1 & * & \cdots & *
\end{bmatrix}$$
where "$*$" are generic non zero elements. Consider now the linear system $E(x)y = 0$, of the form
$$
\begin{cases}
y_1 + (\text{combination of $y_2,\ldots,y_k$})  = 0\\
y_2 + (\text{combination of $y_3,\ldots,y_k$})   = 0\\
\vdots \\
y_d + (\text{combination of $y_{d+1},\ldots,y_k$})   = 0
\end{cases}
$$
and build your basis $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{B}(x)$ of the space $\{E(x)y = 0\}$ (that coincides with $\{H(x)y = 0\}$ ) as follows: 
$$\mathcal{B} = \{b^{(1)},\ldots,b^{(k-d)}\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^k$$
where, for each $m$, the last $(k-d)$ components of $b^{(m)}$ are given by 
$$[b^{(m)}]_{d + i} = \delta_{i,m}, \quad \text{for } i = 1,\ldots,k-d$$
and you can compute the first $d$ components of each $b^{(m)}$ by direct substitution on the linear system $E(x)y = 0$.

Again, the whole process is continuous and now you just have to consider the matrix $K(x)$ that has the vectors of $\mathcal{B}$ as columns.